# Android Eclipse errors on launch

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing an android app using Eclipse.  All has been going well until I tried to deploy it to my device last night.  When I clicked Run, I was presented with the following:

```
[2012-04-26 09:00:52 - Unicyclist] Android Launch!
[2012-04-26 09:00:52 - Unicyclist] adb is running normally.
[2012-04-26 09:00:52 - Unicyclist] Performing com.unicycle.UnicyclistActivity activity launch
[2012-04-26 09:00:52 - Unicyclist] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2012-04-26 09:01:05 - Unicyclist] Uploading Unicyclist.apk onto device 'SH0AZR805746'
[2012-04-26 09:01:05 - Unicyclist] Failed to install Unicyclist.apk on device 'SH0AZR805746': No such file or directory
[2012-04-26 09:01:05 - Unicyclist] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No such file or directory
[2012-04-26 09:01:05 - Unicyclist] Launch canceled!
```

It sounds like the directory it is attempting to install to on the phone is missing.  Or perhaps it's a directory on my computer?  I can't find anything on this by searching, and **I'm not sure how to debug this.**

- This is a phone, not a virtual device.
- The phone is running cyanogenmod, not stock.
- A bunch of apps updated last night (related?)  I re-imaged the phone from a backup, and the app deployed correctly.  Then I updated the apps that had changed since last backup, and left it overnight.  This morning, it won't deploy again (same problem)
- The app launches fine on
  another tablet, and fine in a virtual device
- My dev environment is in   a dropbox folder, if that makes any difference.  I switch between developing on a windows and 2 linux computers.
- Same problem occurs on both linux computers with this phone (haven't tried windows yet)

Comment: have you checked "unknown sources" checkbox in the settings>applications setting page (on the phone)?

Comment: Have you tried copying everything to another folder and testing it from there? You could just import the new folder in. Make sure the application name doesn't exist.

Comment: @Jermin Bazazian - The deploy works fine to another device (tablet) - so wouldn't that indicate the problem is on the device?

Comment: @owen gerig - yes, unknown sources is checked.  As I said, this was working well shortly beforehand.

Comment: You are right but still I would give it a shot. It has happened to me that an application which had been installed on a device ran very well on the same device, simply because not all the files are being transfer. But the moment you switch to a new device errors start to pop up.

Comment: @Jermin Bazazian - same problem from another directory.  But thanks for the idea.

Comment: do you have enough space on your device for the apk? did you try uninstalling your app and reinstalling it?

Comment: Just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450738/failed-to-install-apk-on-device-local-path-doesnt-exist). The suggestion is to build clean. Not sure if it works.

Comment: @Jermin Bazazian - build clean was the answer - why don't you post it as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thank You!

Comment: No problem, you should thank google. I have added my comment as an answer below, just because you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Eclipse is not capable of finding your apk file. Just try build clean. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450738/failed-to-install-apk-on-device-local-path-doesnt-exist) is another similar question.

Comment: Just to clarify, that's "Project | Clean..." in Eclipse.