# com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Local path doesn't exist - While compiling app with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I get the following error sometimes during compling and running the application using eclipse.

> Failed to install ABC.apk on device '4df11bd574734fd9': Local path
>   doesn't exist. [2013-08-20 09:28:04 - ABC]
>   com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Local path doesn't exist.
>   [2013-08-20 09:28:04 - ABC] Launch canceled!

The pop up in eclipse says that, the application contains some errors, which I need to fix. 
I have updated my eclipse and other related things to latest.

I followed all the posts whihc talks about resolving this error, but none of them work for me. I see that once I get this error, my bin folder is kind of locked and I cannot delete it. Currently, the only option left for me is to restart my laptop and then it starts to work again but it is very tedious and time taking.

Can someone suggest me what should I do?

Comment: Possible Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450738/failed-to-install-apk-on-device-local-path-doesnt-exist In short, **CLEAN YOUR PROJECT** :)

Comment: I tried but it didnt work. Whatever I do, the apk in my bin folder is not getting removed. Once I restart my laptop and then only it is possible to clean and build.

Comment: Shift-Delete ? Have u tried that ?

Comment: Yes.. I tried Shift-Delete. bin folder wont get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Well finally I make it. there was a program/process that has blockep miapp.apk file, so when I tryed to clean my App it doesn't drop this file. I stop the program/process and delete manually apk file. now its running great.

Answer (score 1):

okay i found the solution
just transfer all your project directories except bin directory into another folder location of same name as your project name.Now import your project from new location.your project will run this time

Answer (score 0):

Also suffered from this issue. The culprit turned out to be Google Drive, which for some reason locked the .apk file after I shared it to my Drive and then caused all kinds of headaches.

Closing the Google Drive tab fixed the issue.