# eclipse error: Failed to install SAN.apk on device 'emulator-5554': No such file or directory

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

i have developed simple android project to display hello world!!!! but i am getting an error when i run the san project  in android eclipse

```
[2014-03-03 11:07:58 - SAN] ------------------------------
[2014-03-03 11:07:58 - SAN] Android Launch!
[2014-03-03 11:07:58 - SAN] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-03 11:07:58 - SAN] Performing com.san.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-03-03 11:07:58 - SAN] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'BOB' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2014-03-03 11:07:58 - SAN] Uploading SAN.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
```

till this it is running fine but after this statement

```
[2014-03-03 11:07:59 - SAN] Failed to install SAN.apk on device 'emulator-5554': No such file or directory
[2014-03-03 11:07:59 - SAN] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No such file or directory
[2014-03-03 11:07:59 - SAN] Launch canceled!
```

can anyone help in rectifying this error as fast as possible

Comment: ya @innocent killer ....but rajshree said me the answer it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..,it happens soetime

```
 Try window->show view->devices->view menu->Reset adb and again run application.
```

and this also

```
  rightclick on your project--->Run As --->Run Configuration.---->
```

here you will get window   [image]

just folow that..,and try to run..,it will work.

Comment: i need one more help in coding ....I have designed two xml files in layout folders present in android project

Comment: In activity_main.xml i have created one button called "send" if i click that it has to go to mail.xml file how to use onlick i am new to android only i am studying from two days @rajshree

Comment: you have to just perform onclik opreation in your java class.,and for going on another xml or activity call intent

Comment: b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Intent i=new Intent();
     startActivity(i);
    }
   });

Comment: wait i will ask the question can u pls tell me where to add etc ........i will tell u the link here itself pls correct it and tell me

Comment: ya sure...,just post your code..,i see

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172152/codein-android-if-the-button-is-clicked-it-has-to-go-to-another-xml-file @rajshree pls spoon feed me i dont know android but i know java

Comment: did u see it pls add the code there itself

Comment: ya i have seen that..,give me answer on that question

Comment: when i click enter button in activity_main.xml then it has to display main.xml file@rajshree

Comment: hey sister i need your help just check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292993/eclipse-error-the-refactoring-does-not-change-any-source-code?noredirect=1#comment33869825_22292993

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Eclipse is not able to finding your apk file. Just try with clean your project from eclips.
Here is same problem faced by one of the developer.
[Failed to install *.apk on device '*': Local path doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450738/failed-to-install-apk-on-device-local-path-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 0):

**Delete gen and bin folders. Then clean your project and again build and run.
Restart your emulator and run the project.**

If still your problem is not solved try this

Follow this stackoverflow answers

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout)

Here are many great answers which can solve your problem too. Thanks.

Comment: @Snadeep please upvote if you find it useful

Comment: it was very useful what rajshree said above and it works correctly

Comment: what ever u said was also right i didnt check before posting my problem