# Code:in android if the button is clicked it has to go to another XML file

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created a xml file named activity_main.xml and inside that I have created a button named enter.
here is the code below

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/spydabg"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
    android:text="@string/enter_button" /></RelativeLayout> ////if i click enter button it has to go to main.xml and display
```

I have mainactivity.java where should i add the onclick event

`Main Activity.java`:

```
package com.lay.background;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

Comment: you mean you want to go on another screen..,and want to open new layout??

Comment: and what is your second xml file...???

Comment: second xml file i have designed 9 button onto that so if i click enter button in first xml file then it has to go to main.xml

Comment: i wanna open second xml file @rajshree

Comment: ok....,for that wait i post code

Comment: Check this example.. It explains how to start another activity class from current activity class: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it out

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener{
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

}
and in your secon.java

```
public class Second extends Activity {
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.second);
}
}
```

and define your second activity in mainefest.xml.

Comment: hmmmmm good u r excellent in android i will learn from you sister

Answer (score 1):

startactivity(new Intent(getApplicationcontext(),second.class));
and add your activity in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
activity_main.xml


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/spydabg"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
    android:onClick="onEnterClicked"      **<!--ADD LISTENER-->**
    android:text="@string/enter_button" /></RelativeLayout> ////if i click enter button it has to go to main.xml and display
```

Main Activity.java

```
package com.lay.background;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void onEnterClicked(View view)  // **Method to add**
{
  startactivity(new Intent(getApplicationcontext(),SecondActivity.class));
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

In SecondActivity.java extend the Activity as you have done in MainActivity.java and set the setContentView(R.layout.main) as below

SecondActivity.java

```
package com.lay.background;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  // Here set your second xml
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

NOTE:

Dont forget to include your SecondActivity in AndroidManifest file.

Answer (score -2):

Change your oncreate method like this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Button button = findViewById(R.id.button1);
  button.setOnClickLostener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Call Activity you want to go to
            // or setContentView(<Other layout to change>) This needs to refresh all views use at your own risk
        }
    });
}
```

Add code to call new activity in onclick method

Comment: `setContentView` should only be called once per `Activity`. If you want a completely different layout, start a new `Activity`.

Comment: where should i add this code and if my second xml file is main.xml how to write the code pls suggest me

Comment: no in only one project i have created 2 xml files in layout folder