# Eclipse Error: The refactoring does not change any source code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image

i have done one small coding in mainactivity.java and now i have to create another java in src folder in android eclipse but i am not able to do it

i want to create as shown below
[image]

so i want to create new class stackinfoactivity .
[image]

i click on the next after choosing android activity in the menu menu
[image]

i choose blank and hit next
[image]

details entered and click on next button
[image]

instead of creating a class i am getting an error i have added all the unique details is there any problem with my eclipse i need to correct my eclipse

[image]

i clicked on finish button the activity will not get created i have colored the image above

please anyone suggest me how to correct and get rid of this error

Comment: i am unable to understand your problem. What exactly are you trying to do?.

Comment: Clean your project and build it again.

Comment: i am trying to add one more java file but not able to add @WhoAmI

Comment: i will check that way @Shriram

Comment: no i cleaned it is not working @Shriram

Comment: Any other methods u know i willl ask my sister

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if you have older version of ADT plug-in.

You need to update ADT plug-in after updating SDK manager. 
Not just select "Help->Check for Updates" but select "Help->Install New Software..." and select the ADT site to install newer version of ADT plug-in.

The recent version of ADT plug-in is 22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357 
I had the same problem after I upgrade SDK manager and my ADT-plugin is 22.3 at that time. "Check for Updates" always tell me no update available.

Comment: This worked for me check this one instead of above one thanks yaar @Maruku you are a very good pal thank you the big issue is solved

Comment: my eclipse only changed totally.

Comment: I used the update site: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also like following way.

Right click on your Package name that is `com.redpot.stockquote` folder of your project then select **new** then select **class** you will get window like following images. (Please follow link as i don't have enough reputation to post images here)

http://share.pho.to/4tXRY

Here in **Name** just enter your activity name like **StockInfiActivity**. And then select **Finish** and you will see your Activity in your src folder.

Comment: @Sandeep, try this solution and let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: ya sure give me some time i will reply

Comment: no u cant do it ..it will create default package and create onto it

Comment: Okay @Sandeep, i got you, do one thing right click on your package name that is com.redpot.stockquote instead of src folder and follow the same step.

Comment: @Sandeep, Please accept this answer by clicking right below my answer if it helped you.

Comment: my all the eclipse IDE is only changed with different fragment and all i dont know how to code only now