# How Can I Create Activity (ADT) without the refactoring does not change any source code creating activity error?

Tags: eclipse, android-activity, adt

When I want to create an activity on Android Develop Tools , I take an error like that "the refactoring does not change any source code creating activity".
ADT is allright.
SDK menager updates're allright.
What is the problem ?
There is no any package in SRC folder .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292993/eclipse-error-the-refactoring-does-not-change-any-source-code

Comment: I saw this question many times but there no problem about ADT plungin. Because when I apply these steps these commands appears "  "Android DDMS" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead." for every checked point.

Comment: What version of the ADT plugin do you have installed?

Comment: I use these "ADT Eklentisi - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/". So , I am using https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ link to install plugin.

Comment: Can you post the exact steps you're using to create an Activity?  Is this happening when you create a new android project?  Are you creating a "blank activity" or a template activity?  Which SDK version are you using?

Every reference out there says to reinstall/update the ADT Bundle using https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: Upsss man , thanks I did a mistake when I create application project that's why I took this problem. I forgot choose Blank Activity.Thanks for your attention.

Comment: No problem!  Glad you got it working.