# Error when creating new android activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, eclipse-luna

I recently updated from Eclipse Juno to Luna and I also updated the sdk manager. But when I try to create a new activity, I follow all the steps but at the end I get this screen:

[image: The refactoring does not change any source code]

I also followed the steps in this thread: [Eclipse Error: The refactoring does not change any source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292993/eclipse-error-the-refactoring-does-not-change-any-source-code)

I updated the ADT plugin to most recent version 23.0.4, but this doesn't solve the issue. Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Change the version of java compiler to Java 1.7
**Window -> Preferences -> Compiler**
Restart Eclipse

It works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

It's happen because your ADT eclipse plugin is not compatibility with your Android SDK version. Try to use the older SDK version. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I completely reinstalled eclipse and that fixed the issue